Is "sports betting" on-topic?
Prompted by this question:

The Application of Quantitative Finance in Sports Betting

I really think that this question is about sports betting, even though it tries to present itself as relevant to quantitative finance.  As such, I don't think that gambling questions should be permitted.

We are still in private beta and our #1 goal should be to accumulate a wealth of on topic questions/answers when we go public beta. Gambling is far and few in between while we still have many on topic questions left unanswered.
I'd say let focus our energy on getting those first and table this. There is no reason to not consider this at a later point.
As someone who run a good size community, I can tell you from first hand experience that it's easier to detect spammers if the questions are very on topic. Once you allow gambling, you just invite people who plant these questions that seem innocent at first glance but later put spam links in it.

I really disagree with the other answers.  The mathematics involved in finance also shows up other areas, such as weather forecasting and in poker and other games.  Does that mean we should allow any kind of gambling questions?  I really hope not.  This site is about finance.  If banks start trading swaps on the superbowl or there's a standardized futures contract for trading based on FIFA games, then it's fair game.  Otherwise I think that it should be excluded.
Not only that, the consensus has already been to eliminate "accounting" and soft, beginner question.  I would much rather introduce these before gambling questions.  We're just opening ourselves up for a world of spam.

I think the weather comparison is misleading.  Betting really is pricing in my view.

There is also a market-making aspect to it that could be modeled.

Computation of Expected Values and the like for the entire operation.

I still think sports betting is on topic iff an answer can apply quant finance principles. There has been a suggestion of treating it as a binary option (which sounds interesting), though there hasn't been any rigor in the discussion. I think the current answers on there aren't any good because the question hasn't been posed correctly.
It's possible the OP really didn't understand it himself and thus can't provide any clarity. In this respect, the stated question suffers from not being specific to a particular need.
Perhaps a better question would have come from actual research in this topic. With more experience in quantitatively determined sports forecasting, this question could have been Moneyball.
